# Plotting duplicate values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

It may seems a basic question but i cant find its solution. I have below mentioned data;

```
  x             y        group
  1  5.010786 47.29396     1
  2  5.010719 47.29402     2
  3  5.010679 47.29400     3
  4  5.010642 47.29399     4
  5  5.010862 47.29398     5
  6  5.010707 47.29399     6
  7  5.010835 47.29396     7
  8  5.010823 47.29397     8
  9  5.010722 47.29400     9
  10 5.010823 47.29397    10
  11 5.010722 47.29400    11
  12 5.010823 47.29397    12
```

I am plotting this data but it ignores the duplicate values for plotting. In the above data there are 12 data points. But below plot is showing only 9. I need to plot each and every point. Can anyone please tell me if its possible ? Secondly, is there any way to prevent rounding of the decimal numbers while plotting. 
(For example; 5.01078627407352 should not be like 5.010786).

[image: plot]

CODE;

```
     df <- data.frame(x = lon_redc, y = lat_redc, group = 1:12)
     g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(group),label = 
     group))
     g <- g + geom_segment(aes(xend=c(tail(x, n=-1), NA),
                      yend=c(tail(y, n=-1), tail(y, n = 1))),
                  arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.7, "cm")))
      g <- g + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + 
      xlab("longitude") +
      ylab("latitude") + geom_text(aes(x = jitter(x), y = jitter(y)), 
      check_overlap = TRUE, size = 7)
      g
```

Comment: Maybe you are interested in `help("options")` and in particular the `digits` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you tell ggplot2 to remove overlapping text. No rounding occurs when plotting, so I don't know what you are referring to there.

```
df <- read.table(text ="    x             y        group
1  5.010786 47.29396     1
2  5.010719 47.29402     2
3  5.010679 47.29400     3
4  5.010642 47.29399     4
5  5.010862 47.29398     5
6  5.010707 47.29399     6
7  5.010835 47.29396     7
8  5.010823 47.29397     8
9  5.010722 47.29400     9
10 5.010823 47.29397    10
11 5.010722 47.29400    11
12 5.010823 47.29397    12", header = TRUE)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = as.factor(group),label = 
                      group)) + 
  geom_segment(data = cbind(head(df, -1),
                            xend=tail(df$x, n=-1),
                            yend=tail(df$y, n=-1)), 
               aes(xend=xend,
                   yend=yend),
                   arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.7, "cm"))) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + 
  xlab("longitude") +
  ylab("latitude") + 
  geom_text(aes(x = jitter(x), y = jitter(y)), 
                               check_overlap = FALSE, size = 7)
g
```

[image: resulting plot]